# Defining new class instance inside other class method - Python

Tags: python, namespaces, instance

I have created a `class1` that has a method `method1` on it, in which I declare a variable as an instance of another `class2`. It looks like this:

```
class class1(object):   
    def method1(self):
        myInstanceOfClass2 = class2()
        # Do some stuff
```

The thing is that I get the following error when I try to run the `method1` from an instance of `class1`:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myInstanceOfClass2' referenced before assignment
```

I could solve it by putting a `global myinstanceOfClass2` inside the `method1`, before assign something to it, but I really don't get why. I read the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) but still don't understand exactly how it worked. Every other variable that is not an instance of an user defined class seem to work just fine when declared inside the `method1` (like integers, or strings per example).

Can someone explain to me how does this work?

EDIT:

I was doing an error I didn't mention in the question because never thought it was one! (And putting my whole code was impossible because too long.) I was actually putting the name of the class as the name of the instance while doing `class2 = class2()` and always thought Python would know the difference between one an the other one. I now changed the name of the instance and everything works just fine.

Comment: Did you try to use class instead of def?

Comment: You're not showing us all of the relevant code. `myInstanceOfClass2` is used somewhere else where it's not defined yet. Please post the *full* stack trace as well, it shows *where* you're referring to an undefined `myInstanceOfClass2`.

Comment: If you are defining classes, use `class` not `def`. And pls show traceback.

Comment: He wants to create an *instance* of a class, and he's doing that part just fine. This is a problem of scope - the fact that a class is involved is not relevant to a `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually did put `class` instead of `def` I'll edit my post. But I actually only use `myInstanceOfClass2` after (never before) declaring it as an instance of `class2`. That is why I don't understand why the error...

Comment: And Lukas, the traceback shows the error in the line where `myInstanceOfClass2` is defined.

Comment: My code is very long that is why I'm not posting it all... I am trying to review it many times to see if there's any mistake I haven't seen.

Comment: Found my error! Never thought it could be this... I was using the name of the class as the name of the instance (which I didn't mention in the question because I thought it was irrelevant). I thought Python would know the difference when doing `class2 = class2()` but it actually doesn't. I changed the name of the instance and worked just fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `def`.

```
class class2(object):
    pass

class class1(object):
    def method1(self):
        myInstanceOfClass2 = class2()

c = class1()
c.method1()
print('got here')
```

works fine for me.

EDIT: the above text is answering the question as it was asked initially (`def` was used instead of `class`). Please see the final EDIT in the first post for a solution to the *actual* problem.

Comment: It actually worked. I'll try to see why it doesn't in my own code...

Comment: As I comment in my question, I was putting the name of the class as the name of the instance. I was actually doing `class2 = class2()` and thought Python would recognize the difference between a class instanciator (with the parenthesis `()`) and an instance name... But it doesn't. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tomasyany would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you? Thanks.

Comment: it is not actually solving the problem, but since you couldn't know what the problem was, and that trying your code let me see what it actually was, I will accepted. Can you just edit it and put that one should always use names for instances that are not the same as the class name? It might help others in the future..